# Cannot create route from one point to another ArcGIS Android

Tags: android, routes, arcgis

I've been trying very hard to create a route between two points(**startPoint, endPoint**). But i am getting the following error:

**Location "Location 1" in "Stops" is unlocated. Location "Location 2" in "Stops" is unlocated. Need at least 2 valid stops. "Stops" does not contain valid input for any route.**

I've posted this question on gis.stackexchange.com and geonet.esri.com and didn't get a reply except one which was not helpful.

My Code:

```
private final String routeTaskURL = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
                userCredentials.setUserToken(token, clientID);
                RouteTask routeTask = RouteTask.createOnlineRouteTask(routeTaskURL, userCredentials);
                RouteParameters routeParameters = routeTask.retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
                NAFeaturesAsFeature naFeatures = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();

                Point startPoint = new Point(36.793653, -119.866896);
                Point stopPoint = new Point(36.795488, -119.853345);

                StopGraphic startPnt = new StopGraphic(startPoint);
                StopGraphic stopPnt = new StopGraphic(stopPoint);

                naFeatures.setFeatures(new Graphic[] {startPnt, stopPnt});
                routeParameters.setStops(naFeatures);

                RouteResult mResults = routeTask.solve(routeParameters);
                List<Route> routes = mResults.getRoutes();
                System.out.println(mResults.getRoutes());

                Route mRoute = routes.get(0);
                Geometry geometry = mRoute.getRouteGraphic().getGeometry();
                Graphic symbolGraphic = new Graphic(geometry, new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.BLUE, 3));
                mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(symbolGraphic);
                System.out.println(mResults.getStops());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I've searched the internet. Many developers were/are facing this problem. I've tried all the solutions but none of them worked. I got **routeTaskURL** from the ArcGIS Routing Sample app. The link which is given in the **[documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/find-a-route.htm)** of ArcGIS maps gives me the 403 error if i open it in the browser.

**Note: "token" and "clientID" is declared in the first step and they both are taken from the ArcGIS developers console where i registered my application.**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your X and Y values are switched. Change to this:

```
Point startPoint = new Point(-119.866896, 36.793653);
Point stopPoint = new Point(-119.853345, 36.795488);
```

See the [`Point` class documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/Point.html) to learn that the constructor parameters are (x, y), not (y, x). The route service you're using has a default spatial reference of 4326, which is unprojected longitude and latitude. -119.866896 and -119.853345 are not valid latitude (y) values, but they are valid longitude (x) values.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem. But can you look at my updated code and see why route is not displaying on map. I've added all the necessary graphic layers.

Code Link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14856322/

Comment: I'm glad that worked. You should create a new question. I'll take a look soon.