# Cannot display route on map ArcGIS Android

Tags: android, routes, arcgis

I am developing an app that calculates a route between two points. The code which is given below can calculate a route between two points. But i cannot display it on map graphically.

Code:

```
private final String routeTaskURL = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    addGraphicLayers();
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
                userCredentials.setUserToken(token, clientID);
                RouteTask routeTask = RouteTask.createOnlineRouteTask(routeTaskURL, userCredentials);
                RouteParameters routeParameters = routeTask.retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
                NAFeaturesAsFeature naFeatures = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();

                Point startPoint = new Point(-119.866896, 36.793653);
                Point stopPoint = new Point(-119.853345, 36.795488);

                StopGraphic startPnt = new StopGraphic(startPoint);
                StopGraphic stopPnt = new StopGraphic(stopPoint);

                naFeatures.setFeatures(new Graphic[] {startPnt, stopPnt});
                routeParameters.setStops(naFeatures);

                RouteResult mResults = routeTask.solve(routeParameters);
                List<Route> routes = mResults.getRoutes();
                System.out.println(mResults.getRoutes());

                Route mRoute = routes.get(0);
                Geometry geometry = mRoute.getRouteGraphic().getGeometry();
                Graphic symbolGraphic = new Graphic(geometry, new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.BLUE, 10));
                mLocationLayer.addGraphic(symbolGraphic);
                System.out.println(mResults.getStops());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

void addGraphicLayers() {
    // Add location layer
    if (mLocationLayer == null) {
        mLocationLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    }
    mMapView.addLayer(mLocationLayer);

    // Add the route graphic layer
    if (mRouteLayer == null) {
        mRouteLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    }
    mMapView.addLayer(mRouteLayer);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.unpause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Get the basemap switching menu items.
    mStreetsMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    mTopoMenuItem = menu.getItem(1);
    mGrayMenuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    mOceansMenuItem = menu.getItem(3);

    // Also set the topo basemap menu item to be checked, as this is the default.
    mTopoMenuItem.setChecked(true);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle menu item selection.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.World_Street_Map:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap);
            mStreetsMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.World_Topo:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mTopoBasemap);
            mTopoMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.Gray:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mGrayBasemap);
            mGrayMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.Ocean_Basemap:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mOceansBasemap);
            mOceansMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Note: mLocationLayer and mRouteLayer both are declared in the first step.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes. **First, when you add your graphics layers, the basemap layer may or may not have been added.** *(Spoiler alert: it has not. It's asynchronous so technically it could go either way, but clearly an in-memory graphics layer is quicker to create than a layer based on a web service.)* The last layer added is on top, so your basemap layer may *(spoiler alert: will)* be on top of your graphics layers and hide them. To ensure that your graphics layers get added after the basemap, **add an `OnStatusChangedListener`:**

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object o, STATUS status) {
        if (STATUS.INITIALIZED.equals(status)) {
            addGraphicLayers();
            mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                //Your thread code as you wrote it
            }).start();
        }
    }
});
```

**Second, the route geometry has a different spatial reference than the map.** The [route service](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route)'s default output spatial reference is WGS 1984, a.k.a. 4326, a.k.a. latitude and longitude. But the ArcGIS Online basemap services--[World Topo Map](http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer), for example--are in Web Mercator, a.k.a. 3857 or 102100. There are two ways to solve this. One way is to use `GeometryEngine` to project the geometry from 4326 to 3857. But a better way is to **tell the route service which spatial reference you want.** This is done by adding the following line of code after getting the `RouteParameters` object:

```
routeParameters.setOutSpatialReference(mMapView.getSpatialReference());
```

Comment: Thanks man you really did solved my problem. Is there any way i can enter longitude(x) and latitude(y) and still be able to calculate a route between two points?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get user input instead of having the values hard-coded? If so, you could use `mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener` with a new [`OnSingleTapListener`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/event/OnSingleTapListener.html) to get the user's input (and use `toMapPoint` and `GeometryEngine.project` to turn it into longitude and latitude). You could also use some Android `EditText` views, but that seems awkward for the user.

Comment: No i mean how can i switch my X and Y values?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. You're already sending longitude and latitude values. That's what `(-119.866896, 36.793653)` and `(-119.853345, 36.795488)` are.

Comment: In my previous question you told me to switch my X and Y values. I want them like this (-119.866896, 36.793653) and (-119.853345, 36.795488). Is it possible?
Previous Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128005/cannot-create-route-from-one-point-to-another-arcgis-android

Thanks again

Comment: When I said to switch X and Y, I meant that it had to be (-119.866896, 36.793653), not (36.793653, -119.866896), because there's no such latitude as -119.866896. If you want to reverse the order of your start and end point, simply switch the declarations of `startPoint` and `stopPoint`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102395/discussion-between-linux-holic-and-gary-s).